# Question on the application of gradients

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Say I have a function $z=500-0.2x^{2}-0.25y^{2}$ which is supposed to model a hill. I understand that at a given point $P=(10,6,471)$, $\nabla z$ at that point will give me the direction of steepest ascent, which I've worked out to be $(-4\hat{\imath}-3\hat{\jmath})$.

But how does one calculate the $slope$ at the same point in a direction that is not the same as $\nabla z$? My understanding is that to calculate the slope in the direction of $\nabla z$, it is simply $||\nabla z||$. But what about the slope at $P$ in the direction $(4\hat{\imath}-3\hat{\jmath})$? Is this just $\sqrt{4^{2}+(-3)^{2}}$ or is my understanding incorrect?

Thanks for your patience, all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z_x = -0.4 x$, $z_y = - 0.5 y$, so $(z_x, z_y)$ at $(10,6, 471) = (-4, -3)$, so far so good.

We have $dz = \mbox{grad } z \cdot dr$. For $dr = e_r dR$ with $e_r = (4,-3)/5$ we get $dz = (-4,-3) \cdot (4,-3)/5 \, dR = (-16 + 9)/5 \, dR = (-7/5) \, dR$ and thus $dz/dR = -7/5$.

Comment: OH! I see. My brain went on holiday. Thanks!